# Aligning Image to the Right w/ Styled Component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, styled-components

I'm fairly new to ReactJS and am using styled components to display an image. The code I have in my App.js is `<StyledImage src={mainimg} alt="hi"></StyledImage>` which displays an image on the left side of the screen. My styling is

```
export const StyledImage = styled.img`
  width: 80%;
`;
```

I've tried justify-content, alignitems... I'm not sure what exactly to type to get it aligned on the right side of its container. Any advice?

Comment: justify-content and align-items are meant for aligning the child components. Try adding display: flex and justify-content: right on its parent container.

Comment: @Archivec its parent container also has other components (such as a navbar), and changing justify-content and display on the parent would alter the navbars look. Do I need to add another div of some sort and alter that, or what is the best way to approach that?

Comment: In which case you could either use justify-self for the image itself (flex-start if its parent is not of display: flex or just "start" if it is), or add another div as you said. There is an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self)

Comment: @Archivec adding justify content (right/flex-start/start) does not seem to be changing any behavior of the img, and adding another div and using display: flex and justifyContent: center is also not changing anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: "right"` as a style.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, you need to set the `justify-content` and `align-item` properties to the parent node of your image to move the child inside your parent. If you don't want to set any properties to the parent then use the `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` to your image.

Comment: In my situation, I would like not to edit the properties of the parent and would also not like fixed or absolute position. I simply want the image to align to the right side of its parent.

Comment: The only way that remains is then to use the margins or padding with the image. But for every screen, you need to apply media queries and change them.